# Hierarchical SQL query, consolidating multiple branches & joining a second table

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to build a hierarchical query against two tables, to show names and IDs of parent groups, the child groups, and child's child group, and so on, until there are no more children. The database is Oracle.

I am working with two tables (simplified):

```
groupName (ID, name)
1, ABC
2, Management
3, Head
4, Assistants
5, Supervisors
6, Staff

groupChildren (ID, childID)
1, 2
1, 5
1, 6
2, 3
2, 4
```

Here is the query I have been working with:

```
select level, lpad ( ' ', level * 1, '-') || a.name, b.id

from groupChildren b, groupName a

where b.id=a.id

start with b.id = 1

connect by b.id=PRIOR b.childid
```

My current results are:

```
1 ABC 1 
2 -Management 2 
3 --Head 3
1 ABC 1
2 -Management 2
3 --Assistants 4
1 ABC 1
2 -Supervisors 5
1 ABC 1
2 -Staff 6
```

I want the results consolidated with duplicates removed, so the results display as follows:

```
1 ABC 1
2 -Management 2
3 --Head 3
3 --Assistants 4
2 -Supervisors 5
2 -Staff 6
```

I did some reading on Common Table Expressions but I feel like I'm missing something more basic, that I should be able to achieve with the "Connect By" function.

Any advice much appreciated. Please be gentle, as I am a relative newb to SQL this is my first question on stack overflow. thank you!

Comment: Don't use old-school hierarchical queries. Use recursive CTEs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using old-school Oracle hierarchical queries you should move on to standard CTEs.

Assuming the following data:

```
create table groupname (
  id number(6),
  name varchar2(20)
);

insert into groupname (id, name) values (1, 'ABC');
insert into groupname (id, name) values (2, 'Management');
insert into groupname (id, name) values (3, 'Head');
insert into groupname (id, name) values (4, 'Assistants');
insert into groupname (id, name) values (5, 'Supervisors');
insert into groupname (id, name) values (6, 'Staff');

create table groupchildren (
  id number(6),
  childid number(6)
);

insert into groupchildren (id, childid) values (1, 2);
insert into groupchildren (id, childid) values (1, 5);
insert into groupchildren (id, childid) values (1, 6);
insert into groupchildren (id, childid) values (2, 3);
insert into groupchildren (id, childid) values (2, 4);
```

The query should look like:

```
with node (id, name, lev, path) as (
  select id, name, 1, '/' || name from groupname where id = 1
  union all
  select gn.id, gn.name, n.lev + 1, n.path || '/' || gn.name
    from node n 
    join groupchildren gc on n.id = gc.id
    join groupname gn on gn.id = gc.childid
  )
select * from node;
```

Result:

```
ID  NAME         LEV  PATH                      
--  -----------  ---  --------------------------
1   ABC            1  /ABC                      
2   Management     2  /ABC/Management           
5   Supervisors    2  /ABC/Supervisors          
6   Staff          2  /ABC/Staff                
3   Head           3  /ABC/Management/Head      
4   Assistants     3  /ABC/Management/Assistants
```

Comment: Fantastic, this worked beautifully. thanks so much for the CTE lesson!